# Connect 23” Apple Cinema HD Display to MacBook Pro USB-C

Tags: display, usb, displayport, cinema-display

I’ve gotten my hands on an older 23” Apple Cinema HD Display and would like to use it with my late 2016 MacBook Pro with only USB-C ports. I’ve researched this issue, and I can only find answers from people using the 30” monitor. The gist is that you need to use Apple’s [Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MB571LL/A/mini-displayport-to-dual-link-dvi-adapter?fnode=0511ee4c414d79ff702fcab32b4942f2f48f96cc250d9789fa83aeda072c6d482784ac6c2b3ac37b023e9a410ea692525f5f8e006a35b7e15ade8c9bac6484538be407dacb71366f74102d3e2ab4a2231ccdbe65f38c9bea3075ce514c6dd039), and then an adapter from Mini DisplayPort to USB-C.

From what I can gather, the 30” monitor was the only model that used a dual-link DVI port, while the 20” and 23” used regular DVI. [Reference](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP79?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US). Is this correct?

If it is, it would mean I could avoid the very costly Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter, and hopefully instead purchase an [Apple HDMI to DVI Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MJVU2AM/A/apple-hdmi-to-dvi-adapter?fnode=0511ee4c414d79ff702fcab32b4942f2f48f96cc250d9789fa83aeda072c6d482784ac6c2b3ac37b023e9a410ea692525f5f8e006a35b7e15ade8c9bac6484538be407dacb71366f74102d3e2ab4a2231ccdbe65f38c9bea3075ce514c6dd039) and an HDMI to USB-C adapter. From Apple’s description of the HDMI to DVI Adapter:

> Use the HDMI to DVI Adapter to connect a single-link DVI digital monitor, **such as the 20-inch or 23-inch Apple Cinema Display**, that includes a DVI connector.

Side note: I obviously need the monitor to run at full resolution at 60hz.

Comment: Thanks for posting back the positive result! Could you please share information on specifically which Belkin adapter you used?

Comment: @ybtch I see now that there’s a new white one available at the Apple Store from Belkin, but this is the one I used at the time: https://www.belkin.com/my/p/P-F2CU038bt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question: The Apple HDMI to DVI Adapter + a Belkin USB-C to HDMI Adapter does indeed work for the 23”. No need for the expensive Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter. Yay!